# My main .cs file is now blank after crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, monogame

I've just had a visual studio crash (2012 - Using Monogame) and now my **main.cs** file in my project shows up as a *blank* text file when opened in Visual studio.

The file itself still shows as 134kb so it isn't blank?  No matter what I do the project cannot find the file .. every other .cs file is fine.

There is no backup that I can find .. I'm hoping there is some way of reading the file and recovering the code.

Comment: If you use notepad  and open that main.cs file it has the content you expect, all 134kb of it?

Comment: Maybe its 134 KB of _whitespace?_   You should look into using _version control_.

Comment: I've tried opening it in notepad and wordpad but it has no content :(  I've tried pretty much everything, file recovery, version restore etc..  I think it's gone, I'm gonna try using a different visual studio version.

Answer (score 0):

Monogame does not have a `main.cs` file.

I will assume is is user created. The `Main()` function is in `Program.cs`.

I would suggest moving to VS 2022 Community Edition, it is free, and Monogame 3.8.1.

Create a new project and copy all of your class files into it, modifying the namespace of each to match the new name.

Copy your content sources and add them with the `mgcb-editor`.